# Data Annotation not found in .NET Standard Library in Mac Visual Studio(Community Version 2017)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, visual-studio-mac

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms application. Every thing was compiling and running before but then another developer who works on Visual Studio Windows version added DataAnnotation to project for validation. Since then I am getting compile time error that DataAnnotation is not found. I created a new MVC web project just to check if DataAnnotation is available for Visual Studio Community Version for MAC. It was available and is working for web projects. I have check my library versions and every thing is up to date.

Long story short; how can I add DataAnnotation for PCL projects in Visual Studio Community on Mac?

Following are the screenshots to give a better understanding of my question.

[This screen shots shows that DataAnnotation is working on MAC if I create a new .NET Core MVC Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4sdH.png)

[DLL is present in .NET standard library for Windows and working just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Z3Z.png)

[But on MAC machine it gives the following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCkgW.png)

Comment: What does your .csproj look like? Your PCL project is directly referencing assemblies that are outside of the PCL profile. It seems to also have a reference to Xamarin.iOS which I believe is incorrect.

Comment: Also if you change your PCL profile to 7 or 44 you can get System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations as part of the PCL profile. However this profile might not supported by Xamarin.Forms - you would need to check.

Answer (score -1):

Use netstandard2.0 it's work. I Create a PCL Project with annotations change and change this.